# Check if path accessible by non-root user

Tags: python, linux, file-permissions

I have an installation script written in Python (in Linux) that runs as root and needs to check whether certain files are readable by a non-root user.

For this reason I can't use os.path.exists() or open(filename) (and catch any exceptions).

Currently I'm thinking of checking the permission bit on each of the files, but the only problem is that I will have to check the permission bits on the path leading up to the filename as well (directories need r+x bits set), which could be very slow process if I have thousands of files.

Is my solution the best one, or are there better alternatives?

edit: I will need the script run as root after the files are checked, so dropping root permissions is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [os.seteuid](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.seteuid) to change the effective user to some non-root user. Then try opening the file. An `IOError` will be raised if permission is denied.

```
import os
os.seteuid(65534)  # user 65534 is `nobody`
filename='/etc/passwd-'
try:
    open(filename,'r')
except IOError as err:
    print(err)

# [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/passwd-'
```

Comment: 65534 is nobody on most modern operating systems (asside from windows), but it's not present on all posix systems.  Portable applications might need to do a bit more work to guess a really good euid.  Perhaps the application should try to read the passwd file as root (to make sure it exists), then try to read the passwd file as 65534 (to make sure it lacks permissions, exception == success), then try to read the target file as 65534 (to actually check the permissions),  if the first two fail, then inform the user to check permissions himself.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that I need the script to run as root after the files are checked.

Comment: @teehoo: You can use `os.seteuid(0)` to reset the effective user to root.

Comment: @unutbu This works! Did not know you could regain root permissions, thanks!

Comment: @teehoo: Right. You can reset the effective user id, but not the real user id. (i.e. `os.setuid(0)` would raise an `OSError`).